# win XP + diagnostic my laptop HW

Tags: windows-xp, laptop

I have laptop lenovo T61 ( ThinkPad type )
From some unknown reason the screen is freezing ( after 3 or 4 hours )

So I can't use the keyboard or the mouse ...-:(

The last chance is only restart the laptop again
So my question is can someone have idea if I can Run some software that make diagnostic on my laptop and give me results about HW problem or something else

Answer (score 0):

You could try to connect remotly to the laptop after it freezes (or better: be already connected when it freezes).

You could use the build in remote desktop server (Win XP pro only) or something like VNC ([TightVNC](http://www.tightvnc.com/))

Comment: sorry I dont have extra computer , so the last option is diag SW

Comment: How unfortunate.
First up you should look into the windows event log (Control Panel -> Management -> Event Log Viewer, or similar).
If you are lucky you will find some errors at the time of the freezes.